# Call built-in CodeIgniter function

Tags: php, codeigniter

Well, let's say that I have 100 calls to "form_input" function. Theses calls includes text(70) and uploads(30).

My uploads were simple before. Now I change a bit and add: image preview and file name preview. but I do not want to change all places (30), I can and it's easy, but Ido not want for now.

I do not want to change "core" files, if this is the way, I prefer to use the function with other name.

```
form_input($p1, $p2, $p3){
   if($p1['type']=='file'){
      //do my lovely upload
   }else{
      //call built-in form_input (this is not a recursive call)
      form_input($p1, $p2, $p3);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you simply name your version `form_input_custom()`?

Comment: Yeah, I know this is one way, but i need to know how to call with the same name, if is possible of course.

Comment: You need to either namespace it, put it into it's own class and call the `class->function()` as needed, or override the original and create additional code which handles uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.

1. Make it a class. Make a new class with your custom form functions and just instantiate it when you need it. While helpers in CodeIgniter are supposed to be classless, this will work well and organize your code better. For example,

   ```
   class CustomFormHelper {
      function form_input() {
          // your code 
      }
   }
   $form_helper = new CustomFormHelper();
   $form_helper->form_input();
   ```
2. Change the function name. As a commenter said, just change the function name, it should be a quick fix.
3. Make a multifunction. **This isn't the cleanest solution** but if you want to unify both, this should do the trick.

   ```
   function form_input_unified($fn, $args) {
       if ($fn == 1) {
           // execute original...
       } elseif ($fn == 2) {
           // do it new way.
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Original form_helper is not a class

Comment: @icssanches Yes, but you can make an isolated class with your own functions. Maybe the question isn't clear, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @icssanches I added the multifunction option EDIT: I think I might be getting it now, do you mean check if the input is a file and if so execute a new function, in that case since you can't modify functions at runtime on PHP, you might want to edit the core file that handles this (isn't clean option but seems like it's whats being asked) https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/477e08f1d6726809660e4841f389493541f7bc07/system/helpers/form_helper.php

Comment: Yeah, but third way the function is with another name.

Comment: @Icssanches There are only two ways to do this. Either runtime modification of a function which isn't possible or editing the core files (which seems like the only option right now.)

Comment: If edit core files is the way, I prefer to with other name.

Comment: @Icssanches Yes, the separate naming is preferable.

Comment: @Icssanches If my answer helper remember to hit the answer button :P